# SystemStackError when implementing Euclid's GCD algorithm with recursion

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm trying to code the Euclid GCD algorithm with Ruby.

```
def euclid(m, n)
  n == 0 ? m : euclid(n, m % n)
end
```

I get the same error for any inputs I have tried: `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`

I think I need help understanding recursion in scripting languages.

Comment: For future reference it's good to provide the *exact* circumstances that cause the error, e.g., which inputs to `euclid` cause the error. In this case, any input, I think?

Comment: @Erol: Dave means the values of `m` and `n` that cause the error. Only insanely large numbers would make this `lcd` reach the recursion limit, I'd say the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Can you post the input values ?

Comment: **I got the same error for any inputs i have tried.
e.g. `euclid 4, 2`

Comment: I don't get any errors when I run your method as `euclid 4, 2`. I get the answer of `2`, which seems right.

Answer (score 2):

your code is fine, just delete the whitespace between `euclid (` to `euclid(`

```
def euclid(m, n)
  n == 0 ? m : euclid(n, m % n)
end
```

Comment: I like using `zero?` for boolean comparison: `n.zero? ? m : euclid(n, m % n)`

Comment: This solution fixes an error with the code, but does not fix the error that the OP was asking about (`stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`)

Comment: Yes, Adrian right. I made spelling error when i write the question.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from solutions that deal with fixing the recursive  call, if it helps, the beauty with euclid algorithm is that it has tail recursion, i.e., you can convert it to an iterative solution.

```
def euclid(m, n)
  while n != 0
    t = n
    n = m % n
    m = t
  end
  m
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is caused by the fact that for your inputs to `euclid`, the function has to call itself too many times and the stack runs out of memory. Your implementation would work fine if there was an infinite amount of memory on the stack. Notice how your version of `euclid` works for small inputs. The problem can be fixed by using iteration instead:

```
def euclid(m, n)
  m, n = n, m % n until n == 0
  m
end
```

Comment: IMO this defeats the purpose of "trying recursion".

Comment: Right, but there is no other way of solving the "system stack error".